# Can't open a PHP file from a JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

On my HTML file, I have a button that has an `onclick` method in a JavaScript `<script>` tag. It activates a function called `deleteRow`, which deletes a row from a table in the HTML page.

Inside the function, there is a loop. In that loop there is an `if` condition which deletes the row. I want to add a code line after the deletion code that opens a PHP file and sends it the current `i` of the loop as GET variable.

The problem is that is that it does delete the row, but it doesn't open the file.

I've tried to do it using:

```
// 1.
window.location.href = "file.php?number=" + num.toString();

// 2.
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "file.php?number=" + num.toString(), true);
xmlhttp.send();

// 3.
location.href = "file.php?number=" + num.toString();
location.reload();
```

For some reason nothing works, not even with a `break;` after the code. I've also tried to do that with `Ajax`.

This is the code of the whole function:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the checked products?");
    if (conf == true) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].querySelector('[type=checkbox]');
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if (rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot Remove all Products");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;

                var num = i + 1;
                // The above code to load the PHP file goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why it isn't working? I have to fix this.

Comment: Are you using chrome/firefox? Open up Developer tools and check out the network & console tabs for errors.

Comment: While your 1st and 3rd options would reload the page (and I assume it's not what you want to happen, considering "ajax" tag) it should work fine and send your request to PHP. Are you sure you're not getting it? As @axlj suggested, check your network tab. And maybe show us what you're doing with received value in PHP?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console or the network tab

Comment: Not errors but you can verify it's sending your request correctly there.

Comment: Another note: `xmlhttp.send()` is asynchronous, meaning: the function will return before the operation has completed.  You may want to `xmlhttp.addEventListener('load', callback)` and put your `location.reload()` inside the callback.

Comment: If you are deleting multiple rows, your variable `i` will change with every iteration. You are changing `window.location.href ` in the loop which will redirect you to whatever value you change it to before your loop can even finish. You need to revise and remove any reload functions to the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are reloading the page before the request can be sent successfully to your PHP file by using the `window.location.href = "file.php?number=" + num.toString();` too soon.

You want to put `window.location.href`only once and after you have successfully made the call to your PHP file.

I have attached the change in your code in a snippet here. You can uncomment the lines that handles the page reload to test but it works for me locally.

```js
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the checked products?");
    if (conf == true) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].querySelector('[type=checkbox]');
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if (rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot Remove all Products");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;

                var num = i + 1;

                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php?number=" + num.toString(), true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                
                // Uncomment the code below to refresh the current page 
                // with the GET parameter
                //window.location.href = window.location.href + '?number=' + num.toString();
                
                // Uncomment the code below to open the test.php page instead
                // with the GET parameter
                //window.location.href = 'test.php?number=' + num.toString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="test" border="1px">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="deleteRow('test')">delete</td>
<td>product name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="deleteRow('test')">delete</td>
<td>product name</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My table is different than the table you posted. In my table there are checkboxes in every row, and below the table there is a button that activates the function and deletes the checked rows. Probably that because of that, your solution doesn't work for me

Comment: In your question, you have indicated that you want to delete **a** row, not multiple rows.

Comment: I've changed my table so every row will have a delete button that will activate a JavaScript function that will remove the row. The function does removes the row, but it still isn't loading the PHP file, although I used the same code you wrote in your code snippet. I simply can't load the PHP file from my JavaScript code...